# HDFS File replace while other applications are accessing data

Tags: hdfs

I have been working on an approach to Refresh HDFS files while other consumers/applications accessing data. I have a HDFS directory which has file accessible for the users which i need to replace with latest incoming data everyday, My refresh process few seconds/milli seconds only. But still the challenge is the jobs which already reads this data for analytics get effected due to this refresh process. My approach to refresh files is instead of writing the spark jobs resulted data into actual data locations where users access, I will first write the data a temporary location and then replace with hdfs file replace API. But still my problem is not solved. Please suggest any solution or a workaround to handle HDFS file replace with no impact on downstream.

```
      val conf: Configuration = new Configuration()
      val fs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf)
      val currentDate = java.time.LocalDate.now
      val destPath = outputPath + "/data"
      val archivePath = outputPath + "/archive/" + currentDate

      val dataTempPath = new Path(destPath + "_temp")
      val dataPath = new Path(destPath)
      if(fs.exists(dataPath)){
        fs.delete(dataPath, true)
      }
      if(fs.exists(dataTempPath)){
        fs.rename(dataTempPath, dataPath)
      }

      val archiveTempData = new Path(archivePath+"_temp")
      val archive = new Path(archivePath)
      if(fs.exists(archive)){
        fs.delete(archive,true)
      }
      if(fs.exists(archiveTempData)){
        fs.rename(archiveTempData, archive)
      }
```

Comment: I guess the cause of the problem is that you delete the original file first before you rename the new one. This leave a small time gap where the file doesn't exist. I'm unfortunately not familiar with HDFS, but a quick research suggests that this shouldn't be necessary. Renaming should automatically remove the old file, and importantly, do so atomically. So I'd suggest just skipping the calls to `delete()`. (Not posting this as an answer as I'm not 100% sure.)

Answer (score 1):

**Simpler approach**

Use 2 HDFS locations cyclically per source or target for loading with table defs t1_x and t2_x respectively, and, use a view_x to switch between t1_x and t2_x likewise.

Queries should always use the view_x.

You can clean up the no longer used HDFS locations in a timely manner prior to next cycle.

The clue is to leave the new and old data around for a while.

**Comment to make**
Only drawback is if a set of queries need to run against the old versions of data. If the changed data is of the nature "added to", then no issue, but if it can overwrite, then there is an issue.

**More complicated approach**

In the latter case, not sure if an issue or not, you need to apply an annoying solution as outlined hereunder.

Which is to version the data (via partitioning) with some value.

And have a control table with current_version and pick this value up and use it in all related queries until you can use the new current_version.

And then do your maintenance.